# Custom paths for Vagrant's files and dirs

Tags: file, vagrant, directory, vagrantfile, chef-solo

I started use Vagrant (+ chef_solo) for my App, and now App's folder contain following files and dirs:

```
  ... app's files

  .vagrant
  Vagrantfile

  Cheffile
  Cheffile.lock

  data_bags

  cookbooks
  projects_cookbooks

  ... app's files
```

It will be great if I can move files related with Vagrant into special directory.
I mean something like this:

```
  ... app's files

  .vagrant
  Vagrantfile

  Vagrant
    Cheffile
    Cheffile.lock

    data_bags

    cookbooks
    projects_cookbooks

  ... app's files
```

In this case I will get only 3 files (dirs) in the root folder of my App

```
  ... app's files

  .vagrant
  Vagrantfile
  Vagrant

  ... app's files
```

I think it will be very good for me and my project.

So, I want to restucture file structure of Vargant files.

Anybody knows how can I do that?
Or stucture of Vargant files is totally hardcoded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a way to make my app's folder better.
If you want to cleanup your project's folder just do following:

(I mean APP is folder of your project on HOST machine)

1) Create **Vagrant** folder in APP folder

2) move following files

```
.vagrant
Cheffile
Cheffile.lock
Vagrantfile
cookbooks
cookbooks_addons
bata_bags
... and all Vagrant-related files
```

into APP/Vagrant folder

3) Add additional line in *Vagrant* file

```
config.vm.synced_folder '..', '/APP'
```

That is all. Now you have all Vagrant-related files into Vagrant folder

Now you should use **vagrant up**, **vagrant ssh**, **vagrant halt** into **APP/Vagrant** folder.

And you should use **/APP** folder in Virtual Machine to get access to yours project code.

Looks pretty good for me!

Answer (score 0):

[vagrant chef provisioning](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/chef_solo.html) has a few variables that you can use so you can already have something like

```
config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
  chef.cookbooks_path = ["vagrant/cookbooks", "vagrant/projects_cookbooks"]
  chef.data_bags_path = "vagrant/data_bags"
end
```

I am not sure of `Cheffile` though, I believe it must be stored with the `Vagrantfile` but I am not fully sure

Comment: chef.cookbooks_path = ["vagrant/cookbooks"]

I tried. But it still create folder APP_ROOT/cookbooks
chef.cookbooks_path -- it's just a way to show additional paths, but not way to change location of default folder.